# I need help to connect WebSocket SignalR

Tags: asp.net, sockets, model-view-controller, signalr

i have a problem to connect my app.js on my hubs/socket.js

when made my js and put the conecction

var stream = $.connection.sockets;

show my this error

app.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined

i coppy a example from other proyect and i don't know how does it work

i made the proyect in asp.net mvc in visual studio 2015

Comment: You need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What is the order of js references you have made?
Also, have you added reference to the signalr jQuery library and signalr/hubs?